# Access query with multiple criteria + allowing null values not working properly

Tags: sql

So I'm trying to write a fairly large query and I know I'm making a noob mistake. After googling for 2 hours I'm throwing the question out there hoping you can see my mistake. Here is what I'm doing using the query designer view:

```
field1 = Not Like "*x*,*y*,*z*,*w*" or is null
field2 = Not Like "*a*,*b*,*c*" or is null
```

on about 10 different fields all with slightly different criteria. I need to include any null values but it isn't working properly. Also, I believe because I'm entering "or is null" it's causing the designer view to repeat that command over and over again on every line of criteria.

Comment: be more specific with your info - "isnt working properly" is meaningless

Comment: need to include null values and it isn't working properly = it's not including null values :P I think i got somewhere though. I'm entering a giant AND query, this and this and this and this on like 15 fields, and each of the 15 fields has multiple criteria. In the query designer i was entering everything on one row for AND. I kept everything on 1 line except the IS NULL function, which i moved to a new row for each field. so now i have a diagonal of "is null" in the query design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
field1 = Not Like "*x*,*y*,*z*,*w*" or field1 is null
field2 = Not Like "*a*,*b*,*c*" or field2 is null
```